# Question on the "ListenBackLog" parameter in WCF netTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, nettcpbinding

According to msdn this parameter means:

> > > controls the maximum number of queued
> > >       connection requests that can be
> > >       pending for a Web service.

Does this parameter have any influence when used in a autogenerated WCF client proxy. (the one that created with svcutil....)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter has effects on the server side binding only